# In the sentence "I went home because it was getting late." the part of "it was getting late" is the sentence pattern S - TV - DO or S - LV - PA?

Tags: parsing

So, in the sentence "I went home because it was getting late." Is the the sentence pattern of "it was getting late" is (Subject - Transitive Verb - Direct Object) or (Subject - Linking Verb - Predicate Adjective)

Answer (score 1):

> it was getting late

*get* is a linking verb, and *was getting* is its past continuous tense.

*late* is an adjective functioning as subject complement.

The sentence structure is hence Subject - Linking Verb - Adjective.

*get* has one of its meanings *to become or start to be*.

> You're getting to be such a big boy, aren't you!

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get)